# Calculus - Find critical points

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need help finding the critical points of this function: 
$f(x)=x-2 \sin x $

I found $f'(x)=1-2 \cos x $ and 
$f''(x)=2\sin x$

I know the next step is to set $f'(x)=0$ but when I do that I get $x=1.047$. 
But looking at the graph I see there is another critical point. How do I obtain this other point?

I also need to find the regions where the graph is concave upward and concave downward.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to solve
$$
0 = f'(x) = 1 - 2\cos(x)
$$
which means that 
$$
\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

This happens for example when $x = \frac{\pi}{3}\simeq 1.047$. But remember that $\cos$ is an *even* function so we also get the solution $x = -\frac{\pi}{3}$. Then remember that $\cos$ is $2\pi$ periodic, so we actually get infinitely many solutions:
$$
x = \pm\frac{\pi}{3} + n2\pi,
$$ 
where $n$ is any integer.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

$$f'(x) = 1 - 2\cos x = 0 \implies \cos x = \dfrac 12 \implies x = \pi/3 \;\text{or}\; x  = 5\pi /3$$ for $x \in [0 , 2\pi]$, and in general $$x = \pm \frac \pi 3 + 2\pi n, \; n \in \mathbb Z$$

ADDED: Note that at $x = \pi/3, \;2\sin x = 2 \sin\left(\frac \pi 3\right) = \sqrt 3 > 0$, and at $x = \frac {5\pi}{3},\;\; 2\sin x = 2 \sin\left(\frac{5\pi}3\right) = -\sqrt 3 < 0$.  And in general $$x = \pi/3 + 2\pi n > 0 \implies f''(x) > 0,\quad x = -\pi/3 + 2\pi n \implies f''(x) < 0, \quad n\in \mathbb N$$

Now what does that tell you about when does $f(x) achieve its maximum, and when its minimum?

Comment: Technically $-\pi/3$ is not equal to $5\pi/3$.

Comment: I didn't say they were equal. I said they are both solutions.

Comment: No, they are two different real numbers. Just because the function $f(x) = \cos(x)$ takes the same value at two different numbers, don't make the two numbers equal ...

Comment: If we're talking angles, $-\pi/3$ is *equivalent to* $5\pi/3$.  But, in general, $-\pi/3\ne 5\pi/3$--the first is a negative real number, and the second is a positive real number.  That's probably what Thomas is pointing out...

Comment: AmWhy, you did say that they were equal ... however, now things look fine (+1).

Comment: I noticed that you had down voted 834 times right after I got a downvote on my answer. Now that I don't have a downvote anymore and after I upvoted your answer, you have 833...

Comment: @Thomas A question I downvoted was deleted almost immediately after I downvoted it, so apparently, the deletion negated the downvote. If you'll view my downvote record, you'll see how rarely I downvote an answer, and have never downvoted a "rival" answer, ever. So I'd have no motivation to downvote a high-quality "rival" answer!

Comment: @amWhy: Sorry for insinuating that.

Comment: @Thomas No offense taken. ;-) I *can* understand why you'd have thought that, but please be assured, I much prefer to be a colleague, and not a competitor! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Clear write-up +1